# Is there DataBound in DataGrid?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagrid, databound-controls

in GridView:

```
proctected sub gridview.DataBound(Byval sender as object, byval e assystemEventArgs) handles gridview.databound
{

}
```

how to  use DataBound in DATAGRID??

Comment: Ok, but there are no braces in VB.NET to define a scope like a method. You are also using a GridView instead of an old DataGrid. This is no question at all in the current state. I would suggest to have a look at msdn first: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx#Y535

Comment: proctected sub gridview.DataBound(Byval sender as object, byval e as systemEventArgs) handles gridview.databound
End sub  how to use databound in datagrid?

Comment: are you understand my question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code based on `OnItemDataBound`

```
   <asp:DataGrid 
   id="ItemsGrid" 
   runat="server"
   OnItemDataBound="Item_Bound"
           .../>

   //Code behind
   void Item_Bound(Object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e) 
   {

      Label1.Text = Label1.Text + " " + e.Item.ItemIndex;

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, your question doesn't make much sense currently. But if you want to handle the GridView's [`DataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.databound.aspx) event (as opposed to the [`RowDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event):

```
Protected Sub Gridview1_DataBound(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Gridview1.DataBound
    Dim grid = DirectCast(sender, GridView)
    Dim dataSource As Object = grid.DataSource
    For Each row As GridViewRow In grid.Rows
        ' do something, looping all rows in the grid with RowType=DataRow '
    Next row
End Sub
```

Comment: oh okay but some task is not working in RowDataBound,, if i work with databound in gridview, it's work fine but the same task is not working in datagrid.rowdatabound

Comment: @ShaiRiyaz: Are you kidding, what task? And also, why do you ask for `DataBound` if you actually mean `RowDataBound`?

Comment: Task is --  Three textbox in datagrid(A,B,C) A*B=c am getting the value (A,B) from rowdatabound in codebehind and passing  those value to javascript function,,, doing operation and showing the result to C